# [PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query]

Tags: sql, playframework

i need help. i am trying to select from database thru sql statement in play framework, but it gives me error, i cannot figure out where the clue is. here is the code:

```
@Transactional
public static Users findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password){
String hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(password);
Query q = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select * from USERS where" + "USERNAME=? and PASSWORD=?").setParameter(1, username).setParameter(2, password);
List<Users> users = q.getResultList();
if(users.isEmpty()){
    return null;
} else{
    return users.get(0);
```

here is the eror message:

```
[PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query]
```

can someone help me please! any help i would appreciate!

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are using pure sql in a ORM (object-relational mapping) query. JPA lets you build queries with your objects and it's properties, not your database tables.

```
TypedQuery<Users> q = JPA.em().createQuery("select * from Users where username= :username and password= :password", Users.class);
q.setparameter("username", username);
q.setparameter("password", hash);
List<Users> users = q.getResultList();
```

That is if your User entity is named Users, it probably is User though.

Comment: thanks, now i get this error: 
PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory

Comment: Is Users your @Entity ? What do you have in it ? (Plural is usualy for admin controllers, that's why it is odd to find a model called Users). Did you try using `Users.find("etc etc")` ?

Comment: yeah, my User is @Entity. I have renamed it back to 'User'. but i get the same error again. the problem is that it cannot find my Entity class, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the real problem, now that I'm sure User is your entity, you can try : `User.find("")` This code is like Select * From User Where... so in your case it could be like this...
`User user = User.find("username = ? AND password = ?", username, hash).first()`

Comment: Also, just a sidenote, you are saving in database using sql, when you could just `User user = new User(blablabla)` and then `user.save()`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some spaces in your query. Try to fix that:

```
"select * from USERS where USERNAME=? and PASSWORD=?"
```

Comment: dont i have to do like this: 
 "select * from USERS where USERNAME='?' and PASSWORD='?'" so that the username will stay in '' ?

Comment: No. Parameters will automatically be inserted, so they are interpreted as the right datatype. A varchar or char parameter, may not be surrounded with ''

Comment: ok thanks it is working now, i had different problem, and now i have different problem :D. anyway, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and replaced the @GeneratedValue from the id and manually put the value of the id it is now working.